# Can Settings API setting generate other settings?

Tags: theme-options, settings-api

I have a Settings API field for an address. The address is stored this form: "Address, City, Country".

Is there any way of creating / generating other options based on the one above? When I save the option I want it to generate and save latitude and longitude variables because I need them in order to display the address on the front-end (Google Map)?

Any ideas how to resolve that? I could do that on front-end but then I will have to request the data for every user, not only once and I don't want to do that (performance & there's 25k/monthly limit of requests). I don't want to create additional Settings API fields neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the [`update_option_{$option}`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/option.php#L259) hook:

```
do_action( "update_option_{$option}", $oldvalue, $_newvalue );
```

Something like:

```
add_action( 
  "update_option_youroptionname", 
  function ($oldvalue, $_newvalue) {
    // process your option value and update/insert options as needed
    // var_dump($oldvalue, $_newvalue);  // debug
    // wp_die(); // debug
  },
  1,2
);
```

Be sure to replace "youroptionname" with the appropriate value.

Comment: I'm going to try it right away, but how to store my options then? Is there any easy way of saving variables in functions.php so I could use them on the front-end? Or do I have to use theme options / settings?

Comment: Alright, I think I'm going to use update_option(), though your hook doesn't seem to work at all, maybe that's because I have an array of Settings API and I'm updating mysettings['something'].